# How to check that two button is clicked at a same time?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my homework assignment:

- On the Top of the screen Give a big button (left to right) and display "Start" on it.
- Divide rest of the screen in two blocks graphically (A and B) leaving some space in
  the bottom for a Big label box (left to right).

  - Once you click on the "start" button, disable it and start a 5 seconds timer (in the
    program) and put the message on the Button itself:
    "keep one finger on each of the box and wait for count down to stop"
    and also append the countdown timer value (e.g. 5, 4, 3, 2, 1) and update it after every
    second passed.
  - Once 5 second timer finishes, check if both the boxes A and B are in touch down 
    (finger touch down) position.
  - If not then throw a OK messagebox "you did not keep your fingers down". and again 
    setup the screen from start and repeat.
  - If the fingers were down then disable the main button and display the message on it:
    "Please lift up your fingers slowly" and start two timers.
  - Record the time until the fingers are lifted up (both separately).
  - Display the two Times in the label box below like:
    "Finger 1 in the box A took X seconds"
    "Finger 2 in the box B took Y seconds"

I am not able to check that both the layout button is clicked. Code below:

Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    int a,b;
    long lastDown;
    long lastDuration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1); //- Divide rest of the screen in two blocks graphically (A and B) leaving some space in the bottom for a Big label box (left to right).
        LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layout2);

        final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btn.setEnabled(false);
            //btn.setText("keep one finger on each of the box and wait for count down to stop");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"keep one finger on each of the box and wait for count down to stop", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    });

        layout1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
public int a;

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "layout1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    this.a=1;

                    return true;
                }
                else this.a=0;
                return false;
            }
        });
    layout2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public int b;

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "layout2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    this.b=1;

                    return true;
                }
                else this.b=0;
                return false;
            }
        }); 


        }

    protected void checkclick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(this.a==1 && this.b==1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "both button is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click on the screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

}
```

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" // divided in 2 equal parts layout which is clickable .
        android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"

        android:text="Start" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
             >
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timer"
                android:text="Time: "
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#00FF66" 
            android:clickable="true"

            android:id="@+id/layout2"
             >

        //hope u can understand this layout .    

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout  // To show label "Finger 1 in the box A took X seconds"
   "Finger 2 in the box B took Y seconds"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"

            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="#FFAAFF" >


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by using boolean flag.

For instance,

```
boolean btn1isclicked = false;
boolean btn2isclicked = false;
```

And in your onClick, change the boolean to true after the button is clicked.

To check if both button is click you can do something like

```
    if(btn1isclicked == true && btn2isclicked == true){
                dosomething();
      }
```

Comment: Once 5 second timer finishes, check if both the boxes A and B are in touch down (finger touch down) position.